# TableViewCell Multiple Editext value repeated during scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

I have tableview with three edittext in each section of cell lies side by side.I want to give input from user interface and after giving all values while i click on Button some mathematical calculation will be done to give result.

But edittext value is getting repeated while scrolling table view.Here is my code snippet.

```
import UIKit

class Density_Price_Calculation_TableView: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var Density_Price_Calculation_TableView: UITableView!    
    @IBOutlet weak var Gravity: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Price: UILabel!

    var phreditText = [String]()
    var densityeditText = [String]()
    var priceeditText = [String]()
    var ArrayOfCell = [Density_Price_Calculation_TableViewCell]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Density_Price_Calculation_TableView.delegate = self
        Density_Price_Calculation_TableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Density_Price_Chemicals_MasterData.instance.getChemical_Names().count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : Density_Price_Calculation_TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "density_price_calculation_cell", for: indexPath) as! Density_Price_Calculation_TableViewCell
        let chemical_names = Density_Price_Chemicals_MasterData.instance.getChemical_Names()[indexPath.row]
        cell.updateViews(chemical_names: chemical_names)
        ArrayOfCell.append(cell)
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func btn_pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var totalSize=0.00, gravity=0.0,price=0.0

        for cell in ArrayOfCell
        {
            totalSize=totalSize + (Double(cell.phreditText.text ?? "") ?? 0)
            let tempPhr=Double(cell.phreditText.text ?? "") ?? 0
            let tempDen=Double(cell.densityeditText.text ?? "") ?? 0
            let tempPrice=Double(cell.priceeditText.text ?? "") ?? 0
            if(tempPhr != 0 && tempDen != 0)
            {
                gravity=gravity + tempPhr/tempDen
            }

            price = price + (tempPhr*tempPrice)  
        }

        Gravity.text = String (format : "%.3f",(Double(totalSize/gravity)))
        Price.text = String (format : "%.3f",(Double(price/totalSize)))  
   }
}
```

My TableviewCell Content

```
import UIKit

class Density_Price_Calculation_TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var chemical_name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var phreditText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var densityeditText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceeditText: UITextField!

    func updateViews(chemical_names:Density_Price_Calculation) {
        chemical_name.text = chemical_names.chemical_name
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // Dismiss the keyboard when the view is tapped on
        phreditText.resignFirstResponder()
        densityeditText.resignFirstResponder()
        priceeditText.resignFirstResponder()   
    }   
}
```

[TableView Each Cell Content Image for referrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r41mg.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Don't put your cells in an array; cells are reused. You need to ensure that you update your data model as the text field in cell changes so that you can restore it the next time you are asked for that cell.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you are **dequeuing** the table view cell in `cellForRowAt` and maintaining the same in the `ArrayOfCell` and due to dequeue reference this issue could have occurred.
So try the following changes,
Instead of

```
let cell : Density_Price_Calculation_TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "density_price_calculation_cell", for: indexPath) as! Density_Price_Calculation_TableViewCell
```

Try using,

```
let cell = Density_Price_Calculation_TableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "density_price_calculation_cell")
```

Note*
- This process could be little performance intensive since we are not dequeuing the cell.

Comment: Not working..Showing fatal error while opening the app.